# MongoDB Connection in RobotFramework

Tags: mongodb, robotframework

I am trying to connect to MongoDB using `MongoDBLibrary` in my Robot tests. I have included the library in my tests as well as installed on my system. But still getting `No keyword with name 'Connect To MongoDB' found.`

My Test looks like:

```
Library  String
Library  MongoDBLibrary

*** Variables ***

*** Keywords ***

Connect To DB
  [Arguments]
  Connect To MongoDB  ${DBHost}  ${DBPort}  10  None  <type 'dict'>  False

Disconnect From DB
  Disconnect From MongoDB
```

How can I avoid that error

Comment: which mongodb library are you using? Are you certain it contains a keyword named `Connect to Mongodb`?

Comment: I am using ```MongoDBLibrary``` , [https://github.com/iPlantCollaborativeOpenSource/Robotframework-MongoDB-Library] and I am sure about keywords ```Connect to Mongodb```

Comment: That github link gives a 404.